# get uploaded file path in java web application

Tags: java, jsp, google-app-engine

Since from the 4 days i have been trying to find out the path for the uploaded file. I think it wont possible. Can any one tell me how to get the uploaded file path in java web application. Is there any external API to get the uploaded file path? And my project is google app engine type project. Please some one answer it.

Answer (score 2):

As you can't write to the file system it's likely you can't do whatever it is you are trying to do. So you need to use one of the storage options available instead, likely GCS.

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/googlecloudstorageclient/

> Google Cloud Storage is useful for storing and serving large files.
>   Additionally, Cloud Storage offers the use of access control lists
>   (ACLs), and the ability to resume upload operations if they're
>   interrupted, and many other features. (The GCS client library makes
>   use of this resume capability automatically for your app, providing
>   you with a robust way to stream data into GCS.)

Comment: yes ofcourse. I am using the GCS only. But before that i want to get the uploaded file path.

Comment: well, in python at least, you specify the bucket name and the file name. Those, combined, represent the path to the file.

Comment: but i am using java. But i am asking you even before you uploaded to the Google cloud Storage.

Comment: until you do, there is no path.